# Counting allKeys from NSDictionary returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, count, nsdictionary

I am trying to send an NSDictionary to a TableViewController, the data originally comes from a .plist file. I simply want to send an object that exists further down the hierarchy to new TableViewController. But problems occur when I try to count the number of items in numberOfSectionsInTableView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
// Gets the dictionary for the currently selected row
NSDictionary *dict = [[data objectForKey:[[data allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Checks if the key "Room" exists
if([dict objectForKey:@"Room"]) {
    SalesFairSessionTableViewController *sessionViewController = [[SalesFairSessionTableViewController alloc] init];

    // Sets the data in the subview Controller
    [sessionViewController setData:[dict objectForKey:@"Room"]];

    // And the title
    [sessionViewController setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"Title"]];

    // Problem is here... returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    NSLog(@"%@", [[[dict objectForKey:@"Room"] allKeys] count]);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sessionViewController animated:YES];
    [sessionViewController release];
}
}
```

If I just use allKeys like this:

```
NSLog([[dict objectForKey:@"Room"] allKeys]);
```

It returns ("Item 1", "Item 2") in the console.

But when I add the ”count” method like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[dict objectForKey:@"Room"] allKeys] count]);
```

I just get: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[dict objectForKey:@"Room"] allKeys] count]);
```

count gives an `int`, but you print with `%@`, expecting a pointer to an object. Use `%d` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As your code currently stands, you're telling the `NSLog` string to expect an object. `count` returns an `NSInteger`, hence the error. To fix, change this line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[dict objectForKey:@"Room"] allKeys] count]);
```

to this:

```
NSLog(@"%i", [[[dict objectForKey:@"Room"] allKeys] count]);
```